# How can I run my powershell functions at the same time?

Tags: powershell

How can I run my powershell functions at the same time?

I made two functions in powershell, and these two functions must be started at the same time.

If you create a .bat file and run it, errors that were not there occur. So, I will not run it as a .bat file, and try to run it only in VSC or ISE.
At this time, is there a way to run those two functions at the same time?

my code ex

function Token {
}

function Play {
}

Functions 'Token' and 'Play' must be executed at the same time.
and..
Function B uses the value created by function A.

Comment: It should theoretically work with a powershell job and a wait operator at the start. But maybe there are more alterantives out there

Comment: Create a [semaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=net-5.0) with zero free slots and make your functions to use it. After calling the functions, increase semaphore slots.